# Prove all alternating $d$-linear function $f:V^d\rightarrow W$ is antisymmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove all  alternating $d$-linear  function $f:V^d\rightarrow W$  is antisymmetric.

**Definition:** Let $V_1,\ldots,V_d, W$ vector spaces, such that $f:V_1\times\cdots\times V_d\rightarrow W$ is multilinear.
Then $f$ is $d$-linear  when $V_1=\cdots=V_d$.

I don't have idea of how solve this exercise. Can someone give me a hint or how to solve this exercise? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $i, j \in \{1, \ldots, d\}$, $i \ne j$. We wish to prove:

$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) = -f(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n)$$

for arbitrary $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in V^n$.

We have:

\begin{align}
0 &= f(x_1, \ldots, x_i + x_j, \ldots, x_i + x_j, \ldots, x_n)\\ 
&= \underbrace{f(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n)}_{=0} \\
&\quad+ f(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) \\
&\quad+ f(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n) \\
&\quad+ \underbrace{f(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n)}_{=0}\\
&= f(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) + f(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n) \\
\end{align}

Rearranging gives:

$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_n) = -f(x_1, \ldots, x_j, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Special Case:** $d=2$.

Let $f:V\times V \to W$ be alternating. Note that every $(x,y) \in V$ can be written as

Then by assumption, we have that  $f(x,y)+f(y,x)=f(x,y)+f(x,x)+f(y,y)+f(y,x)=f(x+y,x+y)=0$, where the last equality is by assumption.

Hence, we have that $f(x,y)+f(y,x)=0$, or $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$

Can you generalize?

Comment: This is nt part of your question, but the converse holds in a field that is not characteristic $2$.

Comment: very clear thanks

Comment: @Bvss12 no problem.